# How to make y-axis labels overlap for ggplot figures in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

The y-axis for both figures below are the same (i.e., `mpg`) and have the same scale. I would like the figure on the left to overlap the y-axis of the figure on the right such that you can only see the tick marks of the y-axis for the figure on the right.

The code below makes both figures and aligns them however you can still see the y-axis labels for the figure on the right.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=disp,y=mpg)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=hp,y=mpg)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"))

ggarrange(p1,p2,nrow = 1)
```

The ideal output would look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())` to your code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=disp,y=mpg)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=hp,y=mpg)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())



ggarrange(p1,p2,nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for with the following updates in the `p2` `theme`. `theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), text = element_text(size = 16), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())`

Answer (score 0):

You can `pivot_longer` your dataframes, and then use `facet_wrap`:

```
df = tidyr::pivot_longer(mtcars, cols=c("disp", "hp"))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=value,y=mpg)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(name)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes this is one answer but I was avoiding using a `facet_wrap` because the output does not look good (i.e. those titles, can't see tick marks on right plot, changed the scale on x-axis of right plot).